# Application integration to browser

Tags: c#, .net, browser, google-chrome, integration

I'm working on a simple download manager as a project of mine (C# .NET 4) and I was wondering how browser integration is done in applications of this sort.

I've tried to search and came up with nothing, probably because I'm not sure what it is I'm looking for. I was hoping someone could enlighten me and explain how application take over downloads in the browser.

Any bit of information would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: if you thing to run your application when someone download from internet then you need to write plugin for firefox and chrome then they support your application

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to integrate an application to the browser is through NPAPI. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

It would be recommended to develop that in C++ since there are no NPAPI headers for C#.  I believe Chrome will soon have a Downloads Extension API so you can do all this in JavaScript.